# Are there public honeypot logs that I can look at?

Tags: honeypot

Is there a place online where I can see other's honeypot logs and what kind of activities those hackers were up to?

Comment: Did Googling 'honeypot logs' not help? Are you looking for something different?

Comment: If you don't need the specific details, then take a look at the netmenaces twitter account.